# Can't Remove Template Policy (AEM)

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

I don't seem to be able to delete policies for templates in Adobe Experience Manager 6.5. I can keep adding copies of a policy, but I don't see any way to remove them. Does anyone know if this is possible either through the browser editor or CRXDE?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read this article I found on the web https://myaemlearnings.blogspot.com/2018/03/policies-in-editable-templates.html

For example, if you want to delete the policies assigned to a container, the path would be:

```
/conf/{name}/settings/wcm/policies/{name}/components/container
```

Comment: Yes, so far, not via UI, but going into the CRXDE.